# Why is my pygame showing a blank screen on start up after adding a scoreboard? Python crash course. Alien Invasion

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Beginner here in need of help.

I have been following a Python crash course project Alien Invasion using pygame.

Everything was going well until I added a scoreboard to the game and now when I start up the game all that shows is the background screen and none of my sprites or the play button show on the screen.

However if I mouse click in the area of where the play button used to be the game starts and everything appears as normal.

I've tried retracing my steps and have been looking for the problem for  hours! And can't find any difference in my code compared to the book.

Any help or advice would be great! Thanks.

**Main Script**

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group

from settings import Settings
from game_stats import GameStats
from scoreboard import Scoreboard
from button import Button
from ship import Ship
from alien import Alien
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    # Initialize pygame, settings and screen object.
    pygame.init()

    ai_settings = Settings()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    # Make the Play button.
    play_button = Button(ai_settings, screen, "Play")

    # Create an instance to store game statistics and create a scoreboard.
    stats = GameStats(ai_settings)
    sb = Scoreboard(ai_settings, screen, stats)

    # Make a ship, a group of bullets, and a group of aliens.
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
    bullets = Group()
    aliens = Group()


    # Create the fleet of aliens.
    gf.create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)

    # Start the main loop for the game.
    while True:
        gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, stats, play_button, ship,
           aliens, bullets)

        if stats.game_active:
            ship.update()
            gf.update_bullets(ai_settings, screen, stats, sb, ship, aliens,
                   bullets)

            gf.update_aliens(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)

            gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, stats, sb, ship, aliens,
                 bullets, play_button)


run_game()
```

**Game Functions**

```
import sys
from time import sleep

import pygame
from bullet import Bullet
from alien import Alien


def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Respond to keypresses."""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
          fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
    elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
        sys.exit()

def fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
        """Fire a bullet if limit not reached yet."""
        # Create a new bullet and add it to the bullets group.
        if len(bullets) < ai_settings.bullets_allowed:
           new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
           bullets.add(new_bullet)

def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    """Respond to key releases.)"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False



def check_events(ai_settings, screen, stats, play_button, ship, aliens,
           bullets):
    """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            check_play_button(ai_settings, screen, stats, play_button, ship,
                    aliens, bullets, mouse_x, mouse_y)

def check_play_button(ai_settings, screen, stats, play_button, ship, aliens,
         bullets, mouse_x, mouse_y):
    """Start new game when the player clicks Play."""
    button_clicked = play_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y)
    if button_clicked and not stats.game_active:
        # Reset the game statistics
        ai_settings.initialize_dynamic_settings()

        # Hide the mouse cursor.
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

        # Reset the game statistics.
        stats.reset_stats()
        stats.game_active = True

        # Empty the list of aliens and bullets.
        aliens.empty()
        bullets.empty()

        # Create a new fleet and center the ship.
        create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)
        ship.center_ship()


def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, stats, sb, ship, aliens, bullets,
         play_button):
    """Update images on the screen and flip to the new screen"""

    # Redraw the screen through each pass through the loop.
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)

    # Redraw all bullets behind ship and aliens.
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()

    ship.blitme()
    aliens.draw(screen)

    # Draw the score information.
    sb.show_score()

    # Draw the play button if the game is inactive.
    if not stats.game_active:
        play_button.draw_button()

    # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
    pygame.display.flip()

def update_bullets(ai_settings, screen, stats, sb,  ship, aliens, bullets):
    """Update the position bullets and get rid of old bullets."""
    # Update bullet positions.
    bullets.update()

    # Get rid of bullets that have disapeared.
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
            if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
                bullets.remove(bullet)

    check_bullet_alien_collisions(ai_settings, screen, stats, sb, ship,
           aliens, bullets)

def check_bullet_alien_collisions(ai_settings, screen, stats, sb, ship,
          aliens, bullets):
    """Respond to bullet-alien collisions."""
    # Remove any bullets and aliens that have collided.
    collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, aliens, True, True)

    if collisions:
        stats.score += ai_settings.alien_points
        sb.prep_score()

    if len(aliens) == 0:
        # Destroy existing bullets, speed up game, and create new fleet.
        bullets.empty()
        ai_settings.increase_speed()
        create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)

def get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien_width):
    """Determine the number of aliens that fit in a row."""
    available_space_x = ai_settings.screen_width - 2 * alien_width
    number_aliens_x = int(available_space_x / (2 * alien_width))
    return number_aliens_x

def get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship_height, alien_height):
    """Determine the number of rows of aliens that fit across the screen."""
    available_space_y = (ai_settings.screen_height -
                           (3 * alien_height) - ship_height)
    number_rows = int(available_space_y / (2 * alien_height))
    return number_rows

def create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number, row_number):
    """Create an alien and place it in the row."""
        # create an alien and place it in the row.
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    alien_width = alien.rect.width
    alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
    alien.rect.x = alien.x
    alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
    aliens.add(alien)

def create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens):
    """Create full fleet of aliens."""
    # Create an alien and find the number of aliens in a row.
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    number_aliens_x = get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien.rect.width)
    number_rows = get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship.rect.height,
        alien.rect.height)

    # Create the fleet of aliens.
    for row_number in range(number_rows):
        for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
            create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number,
                  row_number)

def check_fleet_edges(ai_settings, aliens):
    """Respond appropriatly if any aliens have reached an edge."""
    for alien in aliens.sprites():
        if alien.check_edges():
            change_fleet_direction(ai_settings, aliens)
            break

def change_fleet_direction(ai_settings, aliens):
    """Drop the entire fleet and change the fleet's direction."""
    for alien in aliens.sprites():
        alien.rect.y += ai_settings.fleet_drop_speed
    ai_settings.fleet_direction *= -1

def ship_hit(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    """Respond to ship being hit by alien."""
    if stats.ships_left > 0:
       # Decrement ships_left.
       stats.ships_left -= 1

       # Empty the list of aliens and bullets.
       aliens.empty()
       bullets.empty()

       # Create a new fleet and center the ship.
       create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)
       ship.center_ship()

       # Pause
       sleep(0.5)

    else:
        stats.game_active = False
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)


def check_aliens_bottom(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    """Check if any aliens have reached the bottom of the screen."""
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    for alien in aliens.sprites():
        if alien.rect.bottom >= screen_rect.bottom:
            # Treat this the same as if the ship got hit.
        # Treat this the same as if the ship got hit.
            ship_hit(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)
            break

def update_aliens(ai_settings, stats, screen,  ship, aliens, bullets):
    """
    Check if the fleet is at an edge,
    and then update the position of all the aliens in the fleet.
    """
    check_fleet_edges(ai_settings, aliens)
    aliens.update()

    # Look for alien-ship collisions.
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(ship, aliens):
        ship_hit(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)

    # Look for aliens hitting the bottom of the screen.
    check_aliens_bottom(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)
```

**Settings**

```
class Settings():
    """A class to store all settings for Alien Invasion."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game's static settings."""
        # Screen Settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 600
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

        # Ship Settings
        self.ship_limit = 3

        # Bullet Settings
        self.bullet_width = 3
        self.bullet_height = 15
        self.bullet_color = 60, 60, 60
        self.bullets_allowed = 3

        # Alien settings
        self.fleet_drop_speed = 10

        # How quickly the game speeds up
        self.speedup_scale = 1.1

        # fleet_direction of 1 represents right; -1 represents left.
        self.fleet_direction = 1


        self.initialize_dynamic_settings()


    def initialize_dynamic_settings(self):
        """Initialize settings that change throuhout the game."""
        self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5
        self.bullet_speed_factor = 3
        self.alien_speed_factor = 1

        # Fleet_direction of 1 represents right; -1 represents left.
        self.fleet_direction = 1

        # Scoring
        self.alien_points = 50

    def increase_speed(self):
        """Increase speed settings."""
        self.ship_speed_factor *= self.speedup_scale
        self.bullet_speed_factor *= self.speedup_scale
        self.alien_speed_factor *= self.speedup_scale
```

**Scoreboard**

```
import pygame.font

class Scoreboard():
    """A class to report scoring information."""

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, stats):
        """Initialize scorekeeping attributes."""
        self.screen = screen

        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.stats = stats


        # Font settings for the scoring information.
        self.text_color = (30, 30, 30)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

        # Prepare the initial score image.
        self.prep_score()


    def prep_score(self):
        """Turn the score into a rendered image."""
        score_str = str(self.stats.score)
        self.score_image = self.font.render(score_str, True, self.text_color,
              self.ai_settings.bg_color)

        # Display the score at the top of the screen.
        self.score_rect = self.score_image.get_rect()
        self.score_rect.right = self.screen_rect.right - 20
        self.score_rect.top = 20

    def show_score(self):
        """Draw score to the screen."""
        self.screen.blit(self.score_image, self.score_rect)
```

**Game stats**

```
class GameStats():
"""Track statistics for Alien Invasion."""

def __init__(self, ai_settings):
    """Initialize statistics."""
    self.ai_settings = ai_settings
    self.reset_stats()


    # Start the game in an inactive state.
    self.game_active = False

    # High score should never be reset.
    self.high_score = 0


def reset_stats(self):
    """Initialize statistics that can change during the game."""
    self.ships_left = self.ai_settings.ship_limit
    self.score = 0
```

**Button**

```
class Button():

def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, msg):
    """Initialize button attributes."""
    self.screen = screen
    self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

    # Set the dimensions and properties of the button.
    self.width, self.height = 200, 50
    self.button_color = (0, 255, 0)
    self.text_color = (255, 255, 255)
    self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

    # Build the button's rect object and center it.
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
    self.rect.center = self.screen_rect.center

    # The button message needs to be prepped only once.
    self.prep_msg(msg)

def prep_msg(self, msg):
    """Turn msg into a rendered image and center text on the button."""
    self.msg_image = self.font.render(msg, True, self.text_color,
         self.button_color)
    self.msg_image_rect = self.msg_image.get_rect()
    self.msg_image_rect.center = self.rect.center

def draw_button(self):
    # Draw blank button then draw message.
    self.screen.fill(self.button_color, self.rect)
    self.screen.blit(self.msg_image, self.msg_image_rect)
```

**Alien**

```
    import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Alien(Sprite):
    """ A class to represent a single alien in the fleet."""

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        """Initialize the alien and set starting position."""
        super(Alien, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings

        # Load the alien image and set its rect attribute.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Start each new alien near the top left of the screen
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        # Store the aliens exact position
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the alien in its current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def check_edges(self):
        """Return True if the alien is at the edge of the screen."""
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.right >= screen_rect.right:
            return True
        elif self.rect.left <= 0:
            return True


    def update(self):
        """Move the alien right or left."""
        self.x += (self.ai_settings.alien_speed_factor *
                        self.ai_settings.fleet_direction)
        self.rect.x = self.x
```

**Bullet**

```
 import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bullet(Sprite):
    """A class to manage bullets fired from the ship"""

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship):
        """ Create a bullet object from the ships current position"""
        super(Bullet, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen

        # Creat a bullet rect at (0, 0) and then set correct position.
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width,
            ai_settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
        self.rect.top = ship.rect.top

        # Store the bullets position as a decimal value
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

        self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
        self.speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor

    def update(self):
        """Move the bullet up the screen."""
        # Update the decimal position of the bullet.
        self.y -= self.speed_factor
        # Update the rect position
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def draw_bullet(self):
        """ Draw the bullet to the screen."""
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

**Ship**

```
import pygame

    class Ship():

        def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
            """Initialize the ship and set its starting position."""
            self.screen = screen
            self.ai_settings = ai_settings

            # Load the ship image and get its rect.
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

            # Start each new ship at the bottom of the screen.
            self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
            self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

            # Store a decimal value for the ships center.
            self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)

            # Movement flag
            self.moving_right = False
            self.moving_left = False

        def update(self):
            """Update the ships position based on the movement flags."""
            # Update ships center value not the rect.
            if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
                self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
            if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
                self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

            # Update rect object from self.center.
            self.rect.centerx = self.center

        def blitme(self):
            """Draw the ship at its current location."""
            self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

        def center_ship(self):
            """Center the ship on the screen."""
            self.center = self.screen_rect.centerx
```

Answer (score 1):

I bet stats.game_active is at fault. If that's False, nothing happens in the while loop. You're missing some relevant code, so I can't tell for sure, but it seems most likely.

Comment: Hi i've added the rest of the code I have so far. I'll have a look and try to work out if I can find the fault you have suggested. I will continue to write the code from the book and hopefully it will come to me. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: It was the stats.game_active that was at fault. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I continued to the next part of the book and doing so I realised in gf.check_events() There was a word missing/not in the correct position. Upon fixing this my screen went back to normal.